# $dx=dy$ is this correct?

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

The definition of $dx$ is "the infinite small width of $x$". Then for variables $x$ and $y$, can we say $dx=dy$?

Comment: This is not clear.  If $x,y$ are two variables, can we conclude that $x=y$?

Comment: @lulu the question is: Does the "the infinite small width of $x$" equal to "the infinite small width of $y$".

Comment: No, since (a priori) $x\neq y$.

Comment: $dx$ is certainly not defined as "the infinite small width of  $x$". This sentence is meaningless.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is the definition of $dx$?

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof This is wrong, $dx$ and $dy$ *do have* several proper definitions: they can be viewed as differential forms, or as true infinitesimals in nonstandard analysis.

Comment: You're right, let me rephrase. In the calculus and analysis most people deal with, $dx$ and $dy$ will not be properly defined; it is better not to work with them separately, as you lack a proper definition.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the relationship between $x$ and $y$.  For example, if $y = x^2$, then, using the chain rule,
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x \implies dy = 2xdx.$$
So, at the point, $(1,1)$, $dy = 2dx$.